# Cast class to its subclass in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-architecture-components

I have a list of a class called Opportunity, which is filled with objects that extend Opportunity. The list can have either CommunityOpportunites or SponsorshipOpportunities.

I override getItemViewType and assign a value to each item based on whichever subclass the object in the relevant postition, and have a different ViewHolder for each:

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {

    return if (opportunityList[position] is SponsorshipOpportunity){

        Log.i(TAG,"Item type is sponsorshipId")

        SPONSORSHIP

    } else{
        Log.i(TAG,"Item type is community")
        COMMUNITY

    }

}

    inner class CommunityViewHolder(var view: CommunityTileBinding):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view.root)
    inner class SponsorshipViewHolder(var view: SponsorshipTileBinding):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view.root)



companion object{
    private const val COMMUNITY = 0
    private const val SPONSORSHIP = 1
}
```

In onCreateViewHolder() I create the proper ViewHolder for the class of the item, and in onBindViewHolder() I attempt to cast the items in the list (of type Opportunity in the constructor) to the subclass of the item in the view:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)

    return when (viewType){

        COMMUNITY->CommunityViewHolder(DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.community_tile, parent, false))
        SPONSORSHIP-> SponsorshipViewHolder(DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.sponsorship_tile, parent, false))

        else-> throw IllegalArgumentException()


    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = opportunityList.size


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

  when(holder.itemViewType){
      COMMUNITY-> {

          (holder as CommunityViewHolder).view.communityOpportunity = opportunityList[position] as CommunityOpportunity
      }
      SPONSORSHIP->{
          (holder as SponsorshipViewHolder).view.sponsorship = opportunityList[position] as SponsorshipOpportunity
          holder.view.postActionText.text = context.resources.getString(R.string.watch_respond)

      }
  }

}
```

However, I get the following class cast exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.model.Opportunity cannot be cast to com.example.model.CommunityOpportunity
```

when I try at the relevant line in onBindViewHolder, even though the log statement confirming that the item is a CommunityOpportunity in getItemViewType() is printed.

Is there a better way to ask, or is there a better way for me to be displaying multiple ViewHolder/Object types in the RecyclerView?

Edit: Here are the relevant xml layouts:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="sponsorship"
        type="com.example.weare8sample.model.SponsorshipOpportunity"/>
</data>

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/tile_background">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="@drawable/tile_background"
        android:imageUrl="@{sponsorship.coverTileUri}">

    </ImageView>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/postActionText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
            tools:text="@string/watch_respond">

        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_36dp">

        </ImageView>



    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <variable
        name="communityOpportunity"
        type="com.example.weare8sample.model.CommunityOpportunity" />
</data>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tile_background"
    android:imageUrl="@{communityOpportunity.mediaImageUri}">

</ImageView>
```

Comment: Can you post the layouts for the items? My assumption is that at least one variable type in the databinding layout is wrong (probably from copy psting the layout?)

Comment: Where does the crash happen? Is it at one of the casts you make in the adapter, or in one of the generated datainbing classes?

Comment: In onBindViewHolder() in the adapter:
when(holder.itemViewType){
      COMMUNITY-> {

          (holder as CommunityViewHolder).view.communityOpportunity = opportunityList[position] as CommunityOpportunity
      }

Comment: Are the names of the tile layout files switched? I don't have many more ideas :S

Comment: Nope. Thanks for trying, though

Comment: Put some breakpoints specially before the casts in onBindViewHolder and see if everything is good there. Then backtrack.
Another thing it could be is a thrid type of Opportunity that gets caught on the `else`  in the `getItemViewType`. You should probably check explicitly and throw like you do on `onCreateViewHolder`. I doubt it's this though :)

Comment: Actually, that's what I just checked and it is that. The problem is in my View Model.

Comment: I'll add an answer to it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an explicit type check for all types in `getItemViewType` and throw if it's an unknown type, to properly handle all cases.

As it is now, if there's a 3rd type of Opportunity, it will be assumed to be of `COMMUNITY` type.

Answer (score 0):

Use sealed class in your Model that is best option for this case

```
sealed class Opportunity {
  data class CommunityOpportunites( 
                 // class fields
             ):Opportunity()
  data class SponsorshipOpportunities(
                                   // class fields
                                      ):Opportunity()
}
```

and in your getItemViewType method should be like this

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = when (list[position]) {
    is Opportunity.CommunityOpportunites-> 0
    is Opportunity.SponsorshipOpportunities-> 1
}
```

and onCreateViwHolder method

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = 
    when (viewType) {
    0 -> ViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item1, parent, 
        false)
    )
    else-> 
     LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item2, parent, 
           false)
    )
}
```

you don't have to use several ViwHolders write ViewHolder inner class like these

```
inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    fun bind() {
        val d = list[adapterPosition]
        when (d) {
            is Opportunity.CommunityOpportunites -> {
                itemView.apply {
                    //bind the data in the list to view you needn't cast d to 
                    //CommunityOpportunites Kotlin smart cast does it for you
                }
            }
            is Opportunity.SponsorshipOpportunities -> {
                itemView.apply {
                    //bind the data in the list to view you needn't cast d to 
                    //SponsorshipOpportunities Kotlin smart cast does it for you
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think this should work :)

Comment: With sealed class you don't need 3rd case beacause sealed class kotlin knows you have only two classes no need to check 3rd case in ViewHolder's bind function and getItemVIewType() function